# Recaptcha works well in localhost but stopped working on site?

Tags: php, recaptcha

I had setup a recaptcha system for contact form and it was working great until i changed the domain to co.in .I did register the the new domain and obtain the new site key and secret key.The code works well in local host but on the site it just fails.

Recaptcha div..Of course i am using my original sitekey and secret keys..

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="SITE KEY" name="spam"></div>
```

Here is  how i get the captcha value

```
var recaptcha = $("#g-recaptcha-response").val();
```

Here is how i verify the captcha for

```
<?Php
include('dbnews.php');
$captcha=mysqli_real_escape_string($nmysqli,$_POST['recaptcha']);

        $secretKey = "SECRET KEY";
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secretKey."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$ip);
        $responseKeys = json_decode($response,true);
        if(intval($responseKeys["success"]) !== 1) 
        {
            echo 'Failed';
            exit;
        }
        else
            echo 'Success';

?>
```

Regardless of how much i try the check always responds Failed..

Comment: Is your site also HTTPS?  I ran into this issue earlier in the year.

Comment: No HTTP..Funny thing is it is working fine on local host..